# Instantiated ScriptableObject changes affecting original ScriptableObject values

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, instantiation, scriptable-object

I'm using ScriptableObjects to store base information for tools, and trying to instantiate a unique SO for every tool in the game, so they all have unique values. The problem is that whenever a value in one clone is affected, the original SO in the inspector, and every SO in the scene is changed alongside it.

Creating unique SO (itemSetup script):

```
public Item baseData;
public Item Data;

public void Awake()
{
    Data = ScriptableObject.CreateInstance<Item>();
    Data = Instantiate(baseData);
}
```

Changing unique SO (use tool script):

```
gameObject.GetComponent<itemSetup>().Data.durability -= 1;
```

Comment: Scriptable objects tend to do that in the editor. Thats normal behavior

Comment: So would everything work in a proper build of the game?

Comment: Should do yes. I havent checked if the build takes the original values on the current used ones. So tbh i ended up making a reset option for what i was doing which was a quest system for rpg.   Of course you should be able to tell by building and running.

Comment: I tried build and running and the issue persisted. Turns out instantiating in Awake() instead of Start does not work the same.

Comment: Awake maybe too early. Start should have done it.